# No puedo responder preguntas en SO español

Tags: soporte, preguntas, respuesta

[image: Esto me aparece]

Trate de responder una pregunta y por alguna razón no me deja.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Por favor lee [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan respuestas desde mi cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) y sigue las recomendaciones que ahí se indican

## Explicación

Revisé tu actividad y observé que tienes varias respuestas pero ninguna con una puntuación positiva, así que parece que en tu caso aplica lo que se indica en el artículo indicado arriba.

No he visto tus respuestas. Podría ser que no tengan puntuación positiva porque no han sido vistas por alguien que siga las etiquetas de las preguntas a las que has respondido o bien podría ser que deban ser mejoradas.

Si sólo has incluído código en tus respuestas, agrega una breve descripción de porqué y cómo responde la pregunta. Me parece que las preguntas que incluyen referencias a fuentes confiables son bien recibidas, así que si no has incluido fuentes, agregarlas podría ayudar a mejorar tu puntuación.

Comment: Gracias eso es puesto que respondi una pregunta y agregue un enlace y este se cayó aunque sirvio de respuesta luego dejo de funcionar y antes de darme cuenta tuve 2 votos negativos puesto que ya no puedo responder. Ya edite la respuesta y cambie el enlace caído con una respuesta propia.

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Cuando se pone un enlace es importante incluir la información más relevante en la respuesta para no depender del enlace en cuestión.

Comment: Gracias por la indicación, ojala y vuelvan a votar positivamente según lei es la unica forma de recuperar el permiso a responder.

Comment: Puedes ayudarme votando positivamente?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/188018/95875 o no es posible?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez No es bien visto pedir votos. Ten un poco de paciencia y si no llegan los votos pide consejos para mejorar tus respuestas.

Comment: Disculpa aun estoy aprendiendo a manejarme en el foro

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez si realizas tus preguntas/respuestas de acuerdo a lo que se define en el [help] tus publicaciones serán bien recibidas de esta forma obtendrás  reputación y evitarías el problema que comentas, saludos!.